# Where does the structure from rake db:structure:dump come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rake

I want to know where `rake db:structure:dump` gets it's structure from!

Development? Staging? Production? I assume development is the standard!

Can I specify the environment where it comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with *every single database-centric command in Rails*, it talks to the database defined by your current environment, *defaulting* to Development.

You can specify the environment for any and *every* Rails command by setting the environment variable `RAILS_ENV`.

To dump your database schema for development:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development rake db:schema:dump
```

To dump your database schema for production:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:dump
```